# Permit horizontal pan events only if the gesture is not already scrolling vertically

Tags: javascript, scroll, touch, hammer.js

I'd like to set up Hammer.js so that I can respond to horizontal pan events. My first attempt looks like this:

```
var mc = new Hammer(document.body);
mc.on("panleft panright", runBind(this, 'updatePosition'));
mc.on("panend", runBind(this, 'finalisePosition'));
```

This almost gets the behaviour that I'm looking for: if I pan left or right, the `updatePosition` function is called, and when I stop panning the `finalisePosition` function is called.

But these functions are also triggered if the gesture drifts left or right while scrolling vertically. For example, suppose I touch near the top of the screen then drag my finger down half the screen: that should register as a scroll event. Now suppose that I continue by dragging diagonally: downwards and to the left. In this scenario, I'd like to ignore the horizontal part of the gesture and treat the gesture as a vertical scroll event only, but Hammer.js is triggering the `panright` and `panleft` events as before.

My next attempt looks like this:

```
var mc = new Hammer(document.body, {
  recognizers: [
    [Hammer.Swipe],
    [
      Hammer.Pan,
      {event: 'panvertical', direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL}
    ],
    [
      Hammer.Pan,                               // RecognizerClass
      {direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL}, // options
      ['swipe'],                                // recognizeWith
      ['panvertical']                           // requireFailure
    ],
  ]
});
mc.on("panleft panright", runBind(this, 'updatePosition'));
mc.on("panend", runBind(this, 'finalisePosition'));
```

This specifies that the horizontal pan events should only be triggered if the `panvertical` event has failed. Sure enough, this prevents the problem I described above. If I begin a vertical scrolling gesture then start to move horizontally, the `panleft` and `panright` events are not triggered. But this version has a more serious probelem: the default scroll behaviour doesn't happen! As a result it's impossible to scroll the app.

Can anyone suggest a better solution?

I'm using Hammer.js version 2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and
I've managed to make it work with this really ugly code

```
   var first = false, lock = false;
   var containerHandler = function(event) {

       if(event.type == 'panend' || event.type == 'pancancel') {
         // iOS bug fix
         lock = false;
         first = false;

       } else if(event.type == 'swipe' && event.direction & Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL) {
         // iOS bug fix
         lock = true;
         first = true;
       }
       else if(event.type == 'panmove') {
         // iOS bug fix ... 
         if(first === false && event.direction & Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL) {
           lock = true;
         }

         first = true;
         if(lock === true)
         return;

         //your code etc...
    };

    var focusMC = new Hammer.Manager(mainContainer[0], {domEvents:true});
    var pan = new Hammer.Pan({threshold: 5, direction:Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL});
    focusMC.add( pan );
    focusMC.on('panstart panmove panend pancancel swipe', containerHandler);
```

small threshold is important..

As far as I remember this issue was only on iOS Safari, but on WP it worked correctly even without this code

**Edit:** Instead of the solution above, try forcing the `touch-action` property
to `pan-y`

I'm keeping both answers as they should all work

Answer (score 0):

Hammer.js will automatically infer a touch-action property based on your recognizers. This might make the application more responsive, but it won't prevent vertical page scrolling just because a user is interacting with the element.

I had the same problem you were having, and found a dead simple solution that works pretty well for a workaround.

```
var isScrolling = false;

var galleryHammer = new Hammer(element, {
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Pan, { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }]
    ]
});

// Making the event listener passive means we don't get any delays between
// the user scrolling and the browser having checked if it should prevent
// that event
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    isScrolling = true;
}, { passive: true });

window.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
    isScrolling = false;
});

galleryHammer.on('pan', function(event) {
    if (isScrolling) {
        return;
    }

    // Normal logic...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (the code comes from a class, and this.hm is simply an Hammer instance):

```
this.hm.on('panleft', function(e){ // ...and same for panright
   if(e.pointerType == 'touch' && (Math.abs(e.deltaY) > Math.abs(e.deltaX))){ return false; }
   // do stuff
}
```

The extra pointerType check is there because I didn't have any issue on desktop computer (mouse events). So the whole is applied ony on touch devices/events.